# How to fix Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

This seems like it is a common problem, but I still don't get it why am I getting this error?

I updated redux and now I get this error:

```
TS2322: Type '(state: ILanguage | undefined, action: PayloadAction<ILanguage>) => ILanguage' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<ILanguage, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Property 'payload' is missing in type 'AnyAction' but required in type '{ payload: ILanguage; type: string; }'.
  > 63 |     language: LanguageReducer,
       |     ^^^^^^^^
    64 |   },
    65 | });
```

This is my reducer

```js
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type ILanguage = {
  isEnglish: boolean;
};

const initialState: ILanguage = {
  isEnglish: true,
};

export const reducer = (state: ILanguage = initialState, action: PayloadAction<ILanguage>): ILanguage => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LanguageActionType.SET_LANGUAGE: {
      const isEnglish = action?.payload?.isEnglish || true;
      return {
        ...state,
        isEnglish,
      };
    }
    case LanguageActionType.RESET_STATE: {
      return { ...initialState };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my action:

```js
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const actionCreators = {
  resetState: () => ({
    type: LanguageActionType.RESET_STATE,
  }),
  setLanguage: (isEnglish: boolean) : PayloadAction<ILanguage> => ({
    payload: { isEnglish },
    type: LanguageActionType.SET_LANGUAGE,
  }),
```

I could suppress the error by modifying this line, basically adding `| AnyAction`:

```js
export const reducer = (state: ILanguage = initialState, action: PayloadAction<ILanguage> | AnyAction): ILanguage => {
```

But I want to understand where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, you have defined the action parameter as action of type `PayloadAction<ILanguage>`, which means it expects an action with a `payload` property of type `ILanguage`, however, the Reducer type from Redux Toolkit expects actions that inherit from the `AnyAction` this latter its property `payload` is optional so here is the conflict.

> Property 'payload' is missing in type 'AnyAction' but required in type '{ payload: ILanguage; type: string; }'

when you give `...| AnyAction` as type for your action it works because the action can be of type `AnyAction` and then treated as `AnyAction`

have a look at [createslice usage with TypeScript](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createslice)

> `createSlice` creates your actions as well as your reducer for you, you don't have to worry about type safety here. Action types can just be provided inline

Comment: could you suggest on how I can modify this code with using `createSlice`?

Comment: I only try to answer the question also if you want to use `createSlice` following docs is always the best approach to learn ;)